# Can't create new project from Android Sample Apps

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Programming and I am trying to create a new project from the sample code provided. I follow the instructions exactly but I keep getting this error:

Could not write file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-10\JetBoy.project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-10\JetBoy.project (Access is denied)

I go check the properties of the directories and they are all read only. When i uncheck that box and re-open the properties, it's still read only!!!!

How can I make these directories not read only so I can u

Answer (score 1):

Easy to fix. Give "Full control" to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples for "Users"

This is a windows 7 / Vista user access problem to that directory. See [How do i open a sample Android SDK app in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588973/how-do-i-open-a-sample-android-sdk-app-in-eclipse)