# Opening Android samples in Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, sample

**My machine**
Windows 7

**Problem**
I'm having trouble opening samples for the Android SDK.
I have successfully ran a "Hello Android".

**Steps I'm doing:**
Make new project -> Create from sample -> (some demo)

**Every error (except APIDemo)**
Could not write file: ...\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-4\samples\LunarLander.project.

Reason:
Could not write file: ...\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-4\samples\LunarLander.project.

**APIDemo error**
A project with that namespace already exists in the workspace

**Things I have tried**
Right click samples folder -> Properties -> Uncheck "Read Only"
   (For some reason, it randomly rechecks Read Only)
Right click samples folder -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> User -> Full Control
Crying
Reinstalling SDK
Google, stackoverflow relevant questions

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably your problem may be similar to this [How do I open a sample Android SDK app in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588973/how-do-i-open-a-sample-android-sdk-app-in-eclipse). If not, you can always try what I've posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

File -> New -> Android Project

Then, select "Create project from existing source", and browse to the samples directory in the SDK directory. Afterwards, choose a build target and click "Finish".

The project should appear in Eclipse as a regular project.

If you get an error doing this, that means that the project already exists in the workspace.