# Open "gradle" project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am an Android beginner and I downloaded the DisplayBitmaps project from the following link:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

It seems that there are no java files under the "src" folder but i find some codes under the folder "java" and a new item called "gradle".

I googled "gradle" and downloaded the eclipse plugin as suggested by the following link:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle-2-3-released

In Windows cmd, i have checked that gradle has been installed in my computer but i just don't know the next steps required in order to execute the project. I searched a long time and a bit confused by the solutions posted online.

It seems that gradle is q common but there are not many well documented tutorials on importing gradle into eclipse. It will be great if anyone would share some useful materials, many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845320/opening-android-samples-in-eclipse or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588973/how-do-i-open-a-sample-android-sdk-app-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Install Gradle Eclipse plugin from this update site: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.6.4.RELEASE/e4.4
(The update site is for Eclipse 4.4.x, put 4.5 at the end of URL if it's Eclipse 4.5 you are using)
Once installed import project as Gradle project. Don't forget to click on "Build Model" in the import wizard once you point to the right folder where the project to import is.
Once Gradle project is properly imported it'll have java nature applied to it and it'll have the appropriate folders...