# How to add an Android Sample to ADT bundle

Tags: android, adt

I'm looking at starting Android Development. I have downloaded the ADT Bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

I wish to look at some of the Android app samples.  In eclipse you can make a new Android App, from a pre existing sample code, like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589246/895

In the ADT bundle none of these three options appear; Only the following window appears.
[image]

How do I add the samples to the ADT Bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to File>> New>>Others.

In the New Dialog, go to Android and select Android Sample Project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`File->New->Other->Android->Android`
 Project From **Exsisting Source**

Comment: please explain in brief what you trying to say here...
that will help to user to understand in very well..

Comment: The Android Sample cannot be added using this.