# how can I Render android view through view class?

Tags: android

Im trying to develop an android app that when the user presses a cwerain number of objects in the screen will check if the user should switch to another view(throgh the pageview class) and change it if nessacery

how can i do that?
after doing the validation on the view class do you know how can i render the view?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just getting started with Android developement (cool!). It would be easier for you if you went through the Getting Started guides in developer.android.com.

Guides like [these](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Personally I would start by experimenting with the samples included in Android SDK. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588973/how-do-i-open-a-sample-android-sdk-app-in-eclipse) on how to to do that.